# Quick question - Can I create a token smart contract now, and handle the distribution of the token later with a separate contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, erc-20

Title really says it all.

I want to create a token, and handle the distribution manually for the time being. If things progress at a later date, I would like to create a smart contract to automatically handle the distribution. At this time I don't intend to create or use this feature.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just assign the tokens to an address you control. Then later you can make a contract that distributes them based on whatever you want to distribute them based on, and transfer them from your address to that contract's address.

You can do the same if you want to control new issuance: Make a function that issues new tokens controllable by a single address, and allow that address to replace itself with a different address. Then later you can create a contract, and replace your address with that contract's address.